# Would like to know where this picture was taken

Tags: italy, where-on-earth, lock-screens

[image]this picture showed up on the Windows Lock Screen and I would like to know where it was taken. I hope you can help me.

Comment: [This page](http://bonpic.com/3/img/1522/lake-garda-italy-night-landscape-nature-lights-mountains-lake-reflection.html) suggests it's Lake Garda in Italy.  Other pictures of that lake look vaguely similar, but I haven't found any that clearly match.

Comment: Bing wallpapers for each day are available [here](http://www.bing.com/gallery/) but I still can't find one for Bing spotlight lock screen

Comment: You can use [Google Images](https://images.google.com/) to find web pages that contain some image. So you can find information about the image.

Answer (score 24):

This photo is of Riva del Garda on Lake Garda, Italy.

The photo is titled [A night suspended in time](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/night-suspended-in-time-royalty-free-image/465077887) by Mattia Bonavida.

You may find several other [photos of this scene and surrounding areas](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/magic-night-on-lake-garda-royalty-free-image/451630557) at Getty Images.